# Explanation of key point of Lagrange 4-square theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was reading the following article about Lagrange's 4 square theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem#The_classical_proof

Where in the 3rd paragraph of the classical proof it is stated "for a and b taking integral values between 0 and (p-1)/2..."

I do not exactly understand why this line is true.

From what I gathered it meant that there must be $a^2$ and $-b^2 - 1$ such that $a^2 \equiv -b^2 - 1 \mod p \rightarrow a^2 + b^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod p $

But how does the pigeonhole principle show this to us?

Comment: How many numbers are there in $[0,(p-1)/2]$? Can we have two disjoint subsets of $[0,p-1]$ of that size?

Comment: There are $\frac{p+1}{2}$ numbers and if we have two disjoint subsets that yields $p+1$ total entries but the size of the interval is $p$ so that's not possible. Having established how do we make the jump that there must be $a^2$ and $-b^2 - 1$ such that $a^2 \equiv -b^2 - 1 \mod p$? How do we ensure that these two sets must take on at least $\frac{p+1}{2}$ different values each to guarantee they share something in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the integer interval $A=[0,(p-1)/2]$ has $(p+1)/2$ elements.

If the function $a\mapsto a^2\pmod p$ from $A$ into the set of residue classes modulo $p$ is injective, its image has size $(p+1)/2$ as well. But the function *is* injective, since $a^2\equiv b^2\pmod p$ implies that $p\mid(a-b)(a+b)$, so $p\mid (a-b)$ or $p\mid(a+b)$. But if $a,b\in A$, and $a\ne b$, both cases are impossible: The former, since $a-b\ne0$ and $a-b\in[-(p-1)/2,(p-1)/2]$, so $-p<a-b<p$. The latter, because $0<a+b<p-1<p$.

By precisely  the same argument, the function $b\mapsto -1-b^2\pmod p$ is also injective on $A$. It follows that the images of these two maps must intersect, since otherwise their union would have size $p+1$ while being a subset of a set of size $p$.

Comment: I still don't understand how can we conclude that the magnitude of the image space is greater or equal to $\frac{p+1}{2}$.

Comment: If a function is injective, the range has exactly the same size as the domain.

Comment: Ah wait! So $w \equiv p-a \mod p$ for all primes $p$ and therefore we know that $1,2... \frac{p-1}{2}$ will be congruent to $p-1, p-2... \frac{p+1}{2}$ respectively when squared since $(p-w)^2 = p^2 -2pw + w^2 \equiv w^2 \mod p$ Thus we have unique values for 1 through $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and of course good old 0 to yield a total of $\frac{p+1}{2}$ possible values

Comment: Yes, exactly.${}$